# D365 WS-Trust deprecation - Microsoft.Xrm.Client

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have a legacy application connected to cloud d365 that uses:

```
XrmServiceContext : Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmOrganizationServiceContext
```

from Microsoft.Xrm.Client namespace. It was downloaded from [there](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032) back then. The connetion string looks like this:

```
"Url=https://org.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;Username=unm;Password=pwd"
```

is the code affected by  [WS-Trust deprecation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming#deprecation-of-office365-authentication-type-and-organizationserviceproxy-class-for-connecting-to-dataverse) announced by MSFT?

Comment: probably yes, you should change auth method (like a clientid/clientsecret)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. You should switch to the following pattern:

```
targetString = string.Format("AuthType=OAuth;Username={0}; Password={1};Url={2};AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d; RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;LoginPrompt=Disabled;RequireNewInstance=true", CRMUsername, CRMPassword, CRMAddress);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Note that those are the "default" AppId and RedirectURI and that in production environments you should register your app and use production values.